# Modeling temporal logging across multiple nodes

Tags: mysql, web-services, database-design, data-structures

I am creating a database for an application that logs data for several different nodes. The data logged looks like this:

- timestamp
- several integer values
- several floating point values
- maybe a string or two

Each node is polled separately.

I would be creating a log entry between every 10 minutes and every 10 seconds (variable logging interval), so I would be looking at (at most) under 10k entries a day per node.

I am wondering how should I structure the database for best data access/management. I imagine I would want to access at least 30 days of historical data, and I want to be prepared for 100s of nodes.

Initially I thought of creating a single table with log data and linking each log entry to a node via 1:1 relationship, but I am afraid that my table will grow too big in this scenario.

Is creating a separate table for each node a viable option?

Any comments/suggestions would be helpful,

Thanks!

Comment: Some questions: data (rows) is inserted. Once inserted, is data ever updated? Is data over 30 days old regularly deleted, or does it just pile up forever? Must you be able to report current data, or can there be a delay (an hour, a day) between when data is generated and that data is made available to a user? What will they be *using* the data for--big reports, trend analysis, fed into a subsequent system? Is sub-second performance critical, for input or output? These and similar questions would drive the OLTP vs. warehouse design decision.

Comment: Answers, in order of questions: Data would not be updated, once logged. After the 30 days, I imagine it would be moved to an archive database, where it would indeed pile up forever (if possible). Ability to report current data is crucial, but we can have a delay of a few minutes. Data will be used for reporting, analysis, possibly fed into subsequent sytems. Sub-second performance is not a factor, resolution of seconds is more than enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading your comments above I would go pretty much the way you first figured:

Create a single table with all the needed information. Your ideas seem fine and since the schema is small, it will be sufficient for the task.

A cron job to archive the data after 30 days is a good idea. If you don't want to move it to another database (table) you can export it as CSV (or similar)  and just store it somewhere.

Some things you should keep in mind:

- Enough space on each of the database server and especially the storage
- Exporting the data in a different format than e.g. CSV may not be the best idea. If your application has another format that can be stored more easily, you *might* consider using the other one.